# Formatting Mac Address in MS Access

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016, mac-address

New to MS Access. Had a question regarding formatting of a MAC Address in one of my Access forms. There is a field I have set up using an input mask aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa;;a where users can manually enter a 48 bit hexidecimal address. e.x 11:44:5E:33:53:AF.

However sometimes there are missing values that occur in this data entry e.x 0:A:B:11:22:C (happens from time to time) but I would like be able to automatically fill the missing values with leading zeros to be like 00:0A:0B:11:22:0C.

I realize that this may not be possible through just MS Access Input masks, but all of the VBA codes and after updates code building I have been looking at so far have not lead me to the desired format.

Thanks for your time and appreciate any help in this!

I tried Format(fieldname, "00000000") code, but it just fills from the left-hand side instead of between the colons. e.x 00:00:0A:B1:12:2C instead of the desired 00:0A:0B:11:22:0C.

Answer (score 1):

My function `FormatMacAddress` is for you:

```vb
' Formats a MAC address using one of the four de facto formats used widely.
' Thus, the format can and will be defined by the specified delimiter to use.
' The default is no delimiter and uppercase.
' Optionally, the case of the returned string can be specified as lowercase.
'
' Examples:
'   None        ->  "1234567890AB"
'   Dot         ->  "1234.5678.90AB"
'   Dash        ->  "12-34-56-78-90-AB"
'   Colon       ->  "12:34:56:78:90:AB"
'
'   Lowercase   ->  "1234567890ab"
'
' 2019-09-23, Cactus Data ApS, Gustav Brock
'
Public Function FormatMacAddress( _
    ByRef Octets() As Byte, _
    Optional Delimiter As IpMacAddressDelimiter, _
    Optional TextCase As VbStrConv = VbStrConv.vbProperCase) _
    As String
    
    Dim LastFrame   As Integer
    Dim ThisFrame   As Integer
    Dim FrameLength As Integer
    Dim Index       As Integer
    Dim Symbol      As String
    Dim MacAddress  As String
    
    ' Only accept an array with six octets.
    If LBound(Octets) = 0 And UBound(Octets) = OctetCount - 1 Then
    
        ' Calculate the frame length.
        FrameLength = DigitCount / DelimiterFrameCount(Delimiter)
        ' Format the octets using the specified delimiter.
        For Index = LBound(Octets) To UBound(Octets)
            ThisFrame = (Index * OctetLength) \ FrameLength
            Symbol = ""
            If LastFrame < ThisFrame Then
                Symbol = DelimiterSymbol(Delimiter)
                LastFrame = ThisFrame
            End If
            MacAddress = MacAddress & Symbol & Right("0" & Hex(Octets(Index)), OctetLength)
        Next
    End If
    
    If MacAddress <> "" Then
        Select Case TextCase
            Case VbStrConv.vbLowerCase
                MacAddress = StrConv(MacAddress, TextCase)
            Case Else
                ' Leave MacAddress in uppercase.
        End Select
    End If
    
    FormatMacAddress = MacAddress

End Function
```

As it requires a Byte() input, you may need the function `MacAddressParse` as well:

```vb
' Parses a string formatted MAC address and returns it as a Byte array.
' Parsing is not case sensitive.
' Will by default only accept the four de facto standard formats used widely.
'
' Examples:
'   "1234567890AB"          ->  1234567890AB
'   "1234.5678.90AB"        ->  1234567890AB
'   "12-34-56-78-90-AB"     ->  1234567890AB
'   "12:34:56:78:90:AB"     ->  1234567890AB
'
' If argument Exact is False, a wider variation of formats will be accepted:
'   "12-34:56-78:90-AB"     ->  1234567890AB
'   "12 34 56-78 90 AB"     ->  1234567890AB
'   "56 78 90 AB"           ->  0000567890AB
'   "1234567890ABDE34A0"    ->  1234567890AB
'
' For unparsable values, the neutral MAC address is returned:
'   "1K34567890ABDEA0"      ->  000000000000
'
' 2019-09-23, Cactus Data ApS, Gustav Brock
'
Public Function MacAddressParse( _
    ByVal MacAddress As String, _
    Optional Exact As Boolean = True) _
    As Byte()
        
    Dim Octets()    As Byte
    Dim Index       As Integer
    Dim Expression  As String
    Dim Match       As Boolean
    
    ' Delimiters.
    Dim Colon       As String
    Dim Dash        As String
    Dim Dot         As String
    Dim Star        As String
    
    ' Create neutral MAC address.
    ReDim Octets(0 To OctetCount - 1)
    
    ' Retrieve delimiter symbols.
    Colon = DelimiterSymbol(ipMacColon)
    Dash = DelimiterSymbol(ipMacDash)
    Dot = DelimiterSymbol(ipMacDot)
    Star = DelimiterSymbol(ipMacStar)
    
    If Exact = True Then
        ' Verify exact pattern of the passed MAC address.
        Select Case Len(MacAddress)
            Case TotalLength1
                ' One frame of six octets (no delimiter).
                Expression = Replace(Space(DigitCount), Space(1), HexPattern)
                Match = MacAddress Like Expression
                If Match = True Then
                    ' MAC address formatted as: 0123456789AB.
                End If
            Case TotalLength3
                ' Three frames of two octets.
                Expression = Replace(Replace(Replace(Space(DigitCount / FrameLength3), Space(1), Replace(Replace(Space(FrameLength3), Space(1), HexPattern), "][", "]" & Star & "[")), "][", "]" & Dot & "["), Star, "")
                Match = MacAddress Like Expression
                If Match = True Then
                    ' MAC address formatted as: 0123.4567.89AB.
                    MacAddress = Replace(MacAddress, Dot, "")
                End If
            Case TotalLength6
                ' Six frames of one octets.
                Expression = Replace(Replace(Replace(Space(DigitCount / FrameLength6), Space(1), Replace(Replace(Space(FrameLength6), Space(1), HexPattern), "][", "]" & Star & "[")), "][", "]" & Colon & "["), Star, "")
                Match = MacAddress Like Expression
                If Match = True Then
                    ' MAC address formatted as: 01:23:45:67:89:AB.
                    MacAddress = Replace(MacAddress, Colon, "")
                Else
                    Expression = Replace(Expression, Colon, Dash)
                    Match = MacAddress Like Expression
                    If Match = True Then
                        ' MAC address formatted as: 01-23-45-67-89-AB.
                        MacAddress = Replace(MacAddress, Dash, "")
                    End If
                End If
        End Select
    Else
        ' Non-standard format.
        ' Clean MacAddress and try to extract six octets.
        MacAddress = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(MacAddress, Colon, ""), Dash, ""), Dot, ""), Space(1), "")
        Select Case Len(MacAddress)
            Case Is > DigitCount
                ' Pick leading characters.
                MacAddress = Left(MacAddress, DigitCount)
            Case Is < DigitCount
                ' Fill with leading zeros.
                MacAddress = Right(String(DigitCount, "0") & MacAddress, DigitCount)
        End Select
        
        ' One frame of six possible octets.
        Expression = Replace(Space(DigitCount), Space(1), HexPattern)
        Match = MacAddress Like Expression
        If Match = True Then
            ' MAC address formatted as: 0123456789AB.
        End If
    End If
        
    If Match = True Then
        ' Fill array Octets.
        For Index = LBound(Octets) To UBound(Octets)
            Octets(Index) = Val("&H" & Mid(MacAddress, 1 + Index * OctetLength, OctetLength))
        Next
    End If
    
    MacAddressParse = Octets
    
End Function
```

Full code at GitHub: [VBA.MacAddress](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.MacAddress).